# Attach .mdf in visual studio for publishing

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How do I attach an mdf, so when publishing in visual studio the program can be installed on multiple machines. Without the database not being there. 
It is just a simple database program with some list boxes, but I want to be able to install it on other computers.